# Display text fetched from html page in UILabel

Tags: ios, swift

I'm parsing a HTML page in Swift and I got a list of titles. However, the titles couldn't be displayed properly in a UILabel. I've parsed other pages and all of them is OK to show, except this page. Following are some of titles:

- VÃ´ trÆ°á»ng cÃ´ng tá»­
- VÃ´ tá»± tháº§n bi
- VÃ´ Æ°u kiáº¿m
- Vong má»nh thiÃªn nhai

I'm not sure what kind of encoding the page uses for its text, but all the titles display well in my browser. Can you help me fix this?

Comment: Are you adding your UILabel to UIwebview ?

Comment: Can you please also explain what encoding your expecting this text to display in ? VÃ´ trÆ°á»ng cÃ´ng tá»­

Comment: @Max No, I use only UILabel. For the text above, I want it to become "Vô trường công tử" which is a Vietnamese word.

Comment: Can you post the URL to the page your are parsing?

Comment: @joern yes, it is https://www.kiemhieptruyen.com/muc-luc/

Comment: I think the page is using Unicode

Comment: How are you parsing the page? Could you post some code?

Comment: The page is using UTF-8 encoding. I was able to parse the content with two methods: 1. using `String.contentsOfURL:` and 2. Loading the page into a `UIWebView` and then parsing it with Javascript. Both methods displayed the text correctly when I put it into an UILabel

Comment: Actually, I used Kama lib to to parse html (searching nodes, then use xpath).

Comment: Then the encoding problem probably lies within that lib.